# Прокрутка по кругу

Tags: jquery, прокрутка

Ищу как реализовать прокрутку изображения по кругу. Погуглил и нашел только это: http://www.queness.com/resources/html/bgscroll/index.html . Но плагин сам по себе плохо написан, и тем более морально устарел. Можете посоветовать варианты лучше?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не знаю на каком основании автор считаете "плагин" плохо написанным и в каком смысле устарел, но [ВОТ](http://jsfiddle.net/cvSMG/4/) Вам мой вариант в догонку на чистом JS

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот что-то [похожее](http://blogeek.ru/demo/eternal-motion/), нашел на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/qa/4313/).